# Crystal X Cross Tab

Tags: crystal-reports

Is there a way to summarize data for a multiple year range in the first column (ex: all sales prior to 2005) yet still summarize per year for years following 2005?

Ex: Sales in $
Column headers: <2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010
Grand totals:
Rows would list individual sales person.

this is to consolidate info on one neat easy to print page

Comment: Glad to help. By the way, if any of the answers below solve your problem, don't forget to check the green check mark ;)

Answer (score 2):

Not a problem:

1. First create a custom formula. It would look something *like*:

   if {year}<=2005 then "2005 and older" else {year}
2. Group your crosstab by this new formula instead of by the year.